# Custom Urls in Codeigniter domain.com/articlename.html

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need to make custom URL in Codeiginter to display links from

domain.com/news/id/1
to
domain.com/article-name.html

i want it dynamic to all news id not just one link

can i do it in codeiginter or not ?

Comment: Yes, are you currently using CodeIgniter in this project or just doing research?

Comment: i have finished my project and i afraid lost my old url that have agood serp in google

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, This is called URL rewrite. I can explain here but the official documentation is far better.

here it is: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

In your **[`config.php`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/config.html)** file do this:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; // this line might actually not be necessary, i forget
```

In **[`routes.php`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)** set this:

```
$route['article-name.html'] = "news/id/1";
```

Let me know if you get any errors.

### UPDATE

**Step 1: Set your default controller in routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'get_article';
```

**Step 2: Set your config.php to put .html on the end**

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

**Step 3: Create the Controller**

```
// path:   /codeigniter/2.1.4/yourAppName/controllers/get_article.php

<?php
class Get_article extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($article = '')
    {
        // $article will be "article-name.html" or "article2-name.html"
        if($article != '')
        {
            $pieces = explode('.', $article);

            // $pieces[0] will be "article-name"
            // $pieces[1] will be "html"

            // Database call to find article name
            // you do this

            $this->load->view('yourArticleView', $dbDataArray);
        }
        else
        {
            // show a default article or something
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: monkeyzeus it will not work for every id i want it dynamic for every article id

Comment: What would you want `domain.com/news/id/2` to be?

Comment: domain.com/new/id/2 will be the title of the news 2 from database
and domain.com/new/id/3 will be domain.com/article3-title-from-database